# Cut an Image into 9 pieces C#

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image splitting into 9 pieces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118150/image-splitting-into-9-pieces)

Though I googled enough but unfortunately failed to find a help. This [Code Project Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4366/Displaying-split-Bitmap-files) also failed to serve me what I actually need.

I have an Image and 9 PictureBox(s) in a WinForm.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("media\\a.png"); // a.png has 312X312 width and height
//          some code help, to get
//          img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, img7, img8, img9
//          having equal width and height
//          then...
pictureBox1.Image = img1;
pictureBox2.Image = img2;
pictureBox3.Image = img3;
pictureBox4.Image = img4;
pictureBox5.Image = img5;
pictureBox6.Image = img6;
pictureBox7.Image = img7;
pictureBox8.Image = img8;
pictureBox9.Image = img9;
```

Here is an example Image for you:

[image]

This is a part of my Picture Puzzle class project. I have done with photoshop images, now want to dynamically cut.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First off, instead of using img1, img2... use an array with a size of 9. Then it's much easier to do this using a couple of loops like this:

```
var imgarray = new Image[9];
var img = Image.FromFile("media\\a.png");
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
  for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    var index = i*3+j;
    imgarray[index] = new Bitmap(104,104);
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgarray[index]);
    graphics.DrawImage( img, new Rectangle(0,0,104,104), new Rectangle(i*104, j*104,104,104), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
    graphics.Dispose();
  }
}
```

Then you can fill your boxes like this:

```
pictureBox1.Image = imgarray[0];
pictureBox2.Image = imgarray[1];
...
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try with this code. It basically creates a matrix of images (like you need in your project) and draws on each `Bitmap` adequate part of the large image. The same concept you could use for the `pictureBoxes` and put them in the matrix.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("media\\a.png"); // a.png has 312X312 width and height
int widthThird = (int)((double)img.Width / 3.0 + 0.5);
int heightThird = (int)((double)img.Height / 3.0 + 0.5);
Bitmap[,] bmps = new Bitmap[3,3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        bmps[i, j] = new Bitmap(widthThird, heightThird);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmps[i, j]);
        g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, widthThird, heightThird), new Rectangle(j * widthThird, i * heightThird, widthThird, heightThird), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        g.Dispose();
    }
pictureBox1.Image = bmps[0, 0];
pictureBox2.Image = bmps[0, 1];
pictureBox3.Image = bmps[0, 2];
pictureBox4.Image = bmps[1, 0];
pictureBox5.Image = bmps[1, 1];
pictureBox6.Image = bmps[1, 2];
pictureBox7.Image = bmps[2, 0];
pictureBox8.Image = bmps[2, 1];
pictureBox9.Image = bmps[2, 2];
```