# Recreate an image from tiles in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have an image that I've broken into 48 tiles (8x6) using something similar to "[Cut an Image into 9 pieces C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625891/cut-an-image-into-9-pieces-c-sharp)". I'd like to send put the tiles back together as the original image in html.

What is the best way to do this?

My first thought was to use a table with 8 columns and 6 rows and simply have an tile in each cell, setting all borders and spacing to 0. I am using the style sheet provided in the answer to [How to remove unwanted space between rows and columns in table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table)

Unfortunately I still have a space between rows.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Picture this</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Reset.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="row">
            <td><img id="displayimage0" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage1" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage2" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage3" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage4" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage5" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage6" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage7" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td><img id="displayimage8" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage9" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage10" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage11" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage12" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage13" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage14" /></td>
            <td><img id="displayimage15" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

The CSS is straight from the [link in the accepted answer](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css).

Here is the screen capture of the output (note the space between rows...

[image]

Comment: Probably should use CSS instead of tables, but you can fix your issue by adding `cellpadding="0"` to the `table` tag (which a couple of the newer answers from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table) allude to)

Comment: I added it and still see the space...
`<body>
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="row">`

Comment: What would it look like in CSS? My rows and column size might change based on the image being displayed.

Comment: Try updating your CSS with [pbaldauf's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26742848/1454048) below, or [one of](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14054704/1454048) [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23793490/1454048).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I first added the margin: 0 and padding: 0 to the CSS and it didn't work. I then tried the link provided  by @admedrew 
[How to remove unwanted space between rows and columns in table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table/14054704#14054704)

adding the following to the CSS worked:

> For standards compliant HTML5 add all this css to remove all space
>   between images in tables:

```
 td img {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: It says I can in two days. Thanks to all that posted on this pbaldauf, admdrew, and myfunkyside for your help on this. This is new to me and I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following **CSS properties**:

```
table {
    border-spacing: 0 !important; //This should normally do the trick
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
```

**EDIT:**
May you overwrite some of the **CSS properties** from your *file*. So try to add the `!important` at the end of your CSS styles.

If this also doesn't help, inspect your *tiles* with *Developer Tools* to see which styles are applied.

Comment: I tried the `!important` flags and it still did not remove the space between rows. I posed the answer after I got it working with one of the links in the comment section. +1 for showing me the `!important` flag