# C# Break up large image for printing to multiple pages

Tags: c#, printing

I am trying to print an image in a imagebox1.
Here is the image.
[image: Picturebox1 Image]
Problem is it only prints part of the image. Here it is in print preview.
[image]

I am looking for a way to break up the large image so I can print it on 2 or 3 pieces of paper.

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender,
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, 0,0);
    }


    private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        PrintDocument tmpDoc = new PrintDocument();
        tmpDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(Tmpdoc_Print);

        PrintPreviewDialog tmpPpd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        tmpPpd.Document = tmpDoc;
        tmpPpd.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: This answer may be of some assistance. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13625948/2440747