# How to split an image into smaller pieces in C#?

Tags: c#, image, pixel

How can I split an image into multiple sub images? Like, would I have to read the pixels and convert it to an image somehow?

For example:

If an image's dimension is 100px (width) and 180px (height) and I wanted to, say, split it as a 4x4, would I read the first 25px for the width and the first 45 px for the height and then just increment it correctly?

If so, what would I store the pixels to? More specifically, would it be saved as an array of bytes, images, etc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image splitting into 9 pieces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118150/image-splitting-into-9-pieces)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try the following code sample (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4118195/);

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
        {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(i*(pictureBox1.Image.Width / 4), 
                                        y*(pictureBox1.Image.Height / 4), 
                                        pictureBox1.Image.Width / 4, 
                                        pictureBox1.Image.Height / 4);

            g.DrawRectangle(pen,r );

            list.Add(cropImage(pictureBox1.Image, r));
        }
    }
```

The other alternative is using `BitMap.Clone`, you may find an example in the following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx).

Comment: Please attribute your sources in future. Failure to do so is seen as plagiarism. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944(v=vs.110).aspx) class to hold the image and its `Clone` method to cut out your rectangles of arbitrary size. As a `Bitmap` it comes with several convenience methods such as [Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx) this overload will save to a stream another allows you to save it to a file.